# How to make synchronous forEach loop and make an Asynchronous request to an API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

Am trying to make an API using an array of parameters and use then use the value to make another API call to get another array. using javascript but am hitting the sand with my back every time.

```
var axios = require('axios');
var otp= [
  'bitcoin', 'cat', 'orange', 'mango', 'bats', 'california'
];
optDetails = [];
const promises = otp.map(info => axios.get(`https://www.iot.com/api/?query=${info}`).then(res => res.data));

const newPromise = Promise.all(promises).then(stateData => {
    optDetails.push(stateData)
    optDetails.map(nextData => axios.get(`https://www.crypto.com/api/?query=${nextData.uuid}`).then(res => res.data))
});

Promise.all(newPromise).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
}, err => console.log(err));
```

But I get this error

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
    at Function.all (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/index.js:13:9)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:654:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:665:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:695:10)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:201:19)
    at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:516:3)
```

Comment: `optDetails.push(stateData)` looks wrong - notice that `stateData` itself is an array

Comment: so how do i append it to the other arrsy or I should just loop it

Comment: Given `optDetails` is empty, just discard it and use `stateData` instead of `optDetails`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your second `.map()`, you're creating another array of promises and you need to return that from the `.then()` handler and use `Promise.all()` with that.

The result of `optDetails.map()` is an array of promises.  You need to use `Promise.all()` on that and then return that new promise. Change this:

```
const newPromise = Promise.all(promises).then(stateData => {
    optDetails.push(stateData)
    optDetails.map(nextData => axios.get(`https://www.crypto.com/api/?query=${nextData.uuid}`).then(res => res.data))
});
```

to this:

```
const newPromise = Promise.all(promises).then(stateData => {
    optDetails.push(stateData)
    return Promise.all(optDetails.map(nextData => axios.get(`https://www.crypto.com/api/?query=${nextData.uuid}`).then(res => res.data)));
});

newPromise.then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
}, err => console.log(err));
```

or just get rid of the intermediate `newPromise` variable entirely:

```
Promise.all(promises).then(stateData => {
    optDetails.push(stateData)
    return Promise.all(optDetails.map(nextData => axios.get(`https://www.crypto.com/api/?query=${nextData.uuid}`).then(res => res.data)));
}).then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
}, err => console.log(err));
```

---

In addition `optDetails.push(stateData)` looks wrong.  I don't know what your data structures actually are, but `stateData` itself is an array (as resolved from the previous `Promise.all()`.  Perhaps you mean `optDetails = stateData`?  Or perhaps you want to concatenate `stateData` onto what's already in `optDetails`?

---

**Simpler Version**

It seems to me that this results in much simpler code if you changed your multiple loops into one loop.  You still end up with the same array of results.

```
var axios = require('axios');
var otp = [
  'bitcoin', 'cat', 'orange', 'mango', 'bats', 'california'
];

Promise.all(otp.map(info => axios.get(`https://www.iot.com/api/?query=${info}`).then(res => {
    return axios.get(`https://www.crypto.com/api/?query=${res.data.uuid}`).then(res2 => res2.data);
}))).then(results => {
    console.log(results);
}).catch(err => {
    console.log(err);
});
```

Comment: Just what I said, so +1 :-)

Comment: @user3424387 - Did you see my "simpler version"?  I think that's quite a bit easier to follow and it might even be a little faster because of how it alternates the requests between the separate hosts.

Answer (score 0):

Your `newPromise` is a promise (created by `Promise.all(…).then(…)`) for `undefined` (the return value of the `then` callback). You'll need to add a `return` there.

Then you are calling `Promise.all` on `newPromise` - but `newPromise` is not an iterable like an array of promises. Maybe you expected it to be a promise for the array of promises created by `optDetails.map()`, but even then: you have to call `Promise.all` right away on the array itself, before returning a promise from the `then` callback.

You are most likely looking for

```
var axios = require('axios');
var otp = ['bitcoin', 'cat', 'orange', 'mango', 'bats', 'california'];

const promises = otp.map(info => axios.get(`https://www.iot.com/api/?query=${info}`).then(res => res.data));
const newPromise = Promise.all(promises).then(stateData => 
    Promise.all(stateData.map(nextData => axios.get(`https://www.crypto.com/api/?query=${nextData.uuid}`).then(res => res.data)))
);

newPromise.then((res) => {
    console.log(res)
}, err => {
    console.log(err)
});
```